# PHP curl automatically sending two requests

Tags: php, curl

Im Using PHP curl for saving website name page name on which user has just clicked and ip address in my database, but the problem curl send 2 requests automatically one with correct data and in other one  just changed the page name to index.php, i want to abort the second request just, means when curl executes one time then no request by curl untill an other click on the same page, hope my discription will help you to find out my error for me, here is my code.

```
**This IS My Curl Code**


$wb_nm = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
$pg_nm = $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];
$usr_ip = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];
$pg_nm_ultr = trim($pg_nm , '/');

$n_url = "localhost/curl/new_page.php";

$data = array(
 "varhost" => $wb_nm,
 "varpage" => $pg_nm_ultr,
 "varip" => $usr_ip
);

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $n_url);

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);

?>



**And This Is new_page.php**



if(isset($_POST['varhost']) && isset($_POST['varpage']) && isset($_POST['varip']))
{
    $web_name = $_POST['varhost'];
    $page_name_ulter = $_POST['varpage'];
    $user_ip = $_POST['varip'];

    define("DB_HOSTNAME", "localhost");

    define("DB_USER", "root");

    define("DB_PASS", "");

    define("DB_DB", "pan");

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DB);
    if(isset($connection)){
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_agencies WHERE weblink = '".$web_name."'";
      $result  = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
      if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          if(isset($row))
          {
           $D_id = $row['domain_id'];
           $D_name = $row['website'];
           if($D_id == 0)
           {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    break;
}
}
}

$date_date  = date('Y-m-d');
$time_stamp = date("H:i:s");

$query_Code = "INSERT INTO user_details (website_domain_id , website_domain_name , page_clicked , user_IP , access_date , access_time) VALUES ('".$D_id."','".$D_name."' , '".$page_name_ulter."' , '".$user_ip."' , '".$date_date."' , '".$time_stamp."')";

$result_Code  = mysqli_query($connection , $query_Code);
if($result_Code)
{
    mysqli_close($connection);

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);`, you can send fields as an associative array.  So this code:

```
$fields = '';

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields, '&');
```

is actually not needed such that `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);` becomes

```
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: Sorry Bro, This trick is not working
Even I Changed my Curl code very much, this is my Code now

<?php
/*USER_DETAILS CURL CODE*/

$wb_nm = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
$pg_nm = $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];
$usr_ip = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];
$pg_nm_ultr = trim($pg_nm , '/');
$n_url = "localhost/curl/new_page.php";
$data = array(
 "varhost" => $wb_nm,
 "varpage" => $pg_nm_ultr,
 "varip" => $usr_ip
);

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $n_url);

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);

?>